# How to check the signature of QuantLib.BlackConstantVol?

Tags: python

`help(QuantLib.BlackConstantVol)` says the following.

```
 |  __init__(self, *args)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |
```

But I am not sure how to get self so that I can print the actual args that can be accepted by this function. What is correct way to get the signature from this kind of function whose detailed signatures are hiddle in the vanilla help page?

Comment: That page doesn't help  https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/termstructures/volatility.html ?

Comment: But my question is to get the signature within python assuming the doc is not available outside.

Comment: "Hiddle" is probably an error in this post: do you mean "hidden"?